P-value of 0 when comparing two treatments using bootstrap method
I am comparing two treatments and doing a t-test or a Wilcoxon test I get p-value of 2.2e-16.
I wanted to try bootstrapping because the samples are large (over 1000 samples) and not equal in length (a 300-sample difference). However, when I try running this code in Rstudio I will get a p-value of 0. Isn't this indicating that there are no values that are bigger than the observed difference? Is that telling me that both treatments are just so different that I do not even get a p-value from their comparison?
Here is a sample of the script I am running the dataset is dummy data, not the actual data but it will result in the same p-value=0
set.seed(123)

# Dummy dataset
dataset1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
dataset2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 15, sd = 2)

combined_df <- data.frame(
 value = c(dataset1, dataset2),
 group = factor(c(rep("Group1", length(dataset1)), rep("Group2", length(dataset2))))
)

# Number of observations
n <- length(combined_df$value)
# Number of bootstrap iterations
B <- 10000

# Bootstrap
variable <- combined_df$value
boots <- matrix(sample(variable, size=n*B, replace=TRUE), nrow=n, ncol=B)

bootstat1 <- numeric(B)  # for mean differences
bootstat2 <- numeric(B)  # for median differences

# Observed differences
observed_means_diff <- abs(mean(dataset1) - mean(dataset2))
observed_medians_diff <- abs(median(dataset1) - median(dataset2))

# Loop to calculate bootstrap statistics
for (i in 1:B) {
 boot_sample <- boots[, i]
 bootstat1[i] <- abs(mean(boot_sample[1:100]) - mean(boot_sample[101:200]))
 bootstat2[i] <- abs(median(boot_sample[1:100]) - median(boot_sample[101:200]))
}

# Calculate p-values
p_value_mean <- mean(bootstat1 >= observed_means_diff)
p_value_median <- mean(bootstat2 >= observed_medians_diff)

Thank you for all the help understanding what is happening here

Neither "large" nor "not equal in length" are reasons to suspect a t-test or Wilcoxon test result might be misleading.   BTW, your bootstrap calculation of the p-value is not quite correct: you ought to include the original statistics within bootstat1 and bootstat2 for this purpose.  That guarantees a nonzero p-value.

Are you sure that R is not just rounding your p-value down?

Whuber thank you when you mean to include them in the bootstats you mean something like this?
bootstat1 <- c(bootstat1, observed_means_diff)
bootstat2 <- c(bootstat2, observed_medians_diff)
p_value_mean <- mean(bootstat1 >= observed_means_diff)
p_value_median <- mean(bootstat2 >= observed_medians_diff)


You don't need to do any bootstrap when your issue is really that you're having trouble interpreting a classical test. The t-test and Wilcoxon are telling you the same thing. The mean of sample 1 is much, much smaller than the mean of sample 2. R afficianados recognize p = $2.2e^{-16}$ this is the smallest floating point precision R can report on a p-value. However, in practice, we only report this result to a couple decimal places, so reporting $p < 0.01$ as your result is far more believable.

Since you already ran your primary test, there's no reason to walk back your planned analysis because of what you saw, you can't dream up some supposedly more stringent analysis to gain a fairer claim of statistical significance. Sometimes the answer really is that a particular design was complete overkill - but you didn't know that at the time.

Your "bootstrap" test is completely wrong because you pool the two samples together and sample from the pooled dataset. This generates data according to the null hypothesis which is fine for a permutation test. But if you are doing a permutation test, then you must perform a sample without replacement of the pooled results - maintaining the group labels, or else permute the group label. You also must include your observed dataset among the permuted values so that a permutation test p-value is never exactly 0. OTOH, a bootstrap sample is a sample with replacement from the empirical data, so no data from Group 1 should be included in Group 2 or vice versa, so that the expected mean difference between groups is always the same. Calculating a p-value from this is a subtle and mathematically challenging topic. I suggest you read this post closely: Computing p-value using bootstrap with R


